# Visual studio Java IDE

Tags: java, visual-studio, ide

Can visual studio 2013 be used as a Java IDE?

Or what Java IDE is similar to visual studio in terms of ease of development?

I have already tried Intellij and Eclipse but they lack as compared with visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will find anything better than IntelliJ, which is by far the best Java IDE out there IMHO.